# How to change class name using js to change navbar icon color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am unfamiliar with javascript but I would like to change the color of my navbar icon. Right now, my navbar is black color with white navbar icon. When I scroll the page, my navbar changes background color to white and the font color changes to black. However, the navbar icon is still white so it disappears when I scroll the page. I can fix this by changing the navbar class from 'navbar-dark' to 'navbar-light'. However, I am not sure how to do this using javascript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .navbar{
        background-color: black !important;
      }
      div.navbar.scrolled {
        background-color: white !important;
      }
       div.navbar.scrolled .navbar-brand{
        color: black !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#uniqueIdentifier"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div id="uniqueIdentifier" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="height:200vh;"></div>
    </header>
    <script>
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        $("div.navbar").toggleClass('navbar-dark');
        $("div.navbar").toggleClass('navbar-light');


        $("div.navbar").toggleClass("scrolled", $(this).scrollTop() > 200);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The class `scrolled` is getting added to header `navbar` - why don't you use CSS to change the navbar icon?

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle dark and light based on the scroll possition

```
$("div.navbar").toggleClass('navbar-light', $(this).scrollTop() > 200).toggleClass('navbar-dark', $(this).scrollTop() <= 200);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .navbar{
        background-color: black !important;
      }
      div.navbar.scrolled {
        background-color: white !important;
      }
       div.navbar.scrolled .navbar-brand{
        color: black !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#uniqueIdentifier"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div id="uniqueIdentifier" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="height:200vh;"></div>
    </header>
    <script>
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        $("div.navbar").toggleClass("scrolled", $(this).scrollTop() > 200);
        $("div.navbar").toggleClass('navbar-light', $(this).scrollTop() > 200).toggleClass('navbar-dark', $(this).scrollTop() <= 200);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```